# Exclude directories with Letters A-Z

Tags: arrays, powershell

Using the code below is it possible to exclude any directories that have any characters A-Z in the directory name and just add directories with numerical values to the array. This was working fine until the developers starting adding new folders into the C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\ directory with the latest versions.
An example of the folder names is 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.4, Install, Bin

```
$Array = Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server" |
         ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
         Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
         foreach { $_.Name }
$TABCMD = "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\" + $Array[0] + "\bin\tabcmd.exe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A streamlined **PSv3+** solution:

```sh
$array = (Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\[0-9]*" | 
          Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime).Name -match '^\d+\.\d+$'
```

- `-Directory` - to limit matching to directories - takes the place of the separate  `? { $_.PSIsContainer }` pipeline segment.
- Wildcard pattern `[0-9]*` limits matches to directories whose names *start* with a digit. Unfortunately, wildcard expressions aren't sophisticated enough to enforce that a variable-length filename be *entirely* composed of digits and periods - unless you're willing to assume a *fixed length*; e.g., `[0-9][0-9].[0-9]` to match something like `10.0`.
  If you cannot make this assumption, the later regular expression-based filtering step via `-match` allows you to weed out false positives; you then don't strictly need the wildcard matching up front, but it's more efficient to limit the potential matches.
- `(...).Name` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to collect the `.Name` property values of all objects returned by the enclosed command in an array.
- `-match '^\d+\.\d+$'` then uses a regular expression to filter the array to only include names such as `10.0` - tweak this as necessary.

---

The **PSv2** equivalent:

```sh
$array = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\[0-9]*" | 
          ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
          Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime | % { $_.Name }) -match '^\d+\.\d+$'
```

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) suggests the following **variant**, which eliminates a separate `-match` operation and also matches names more simply by *excluding* folders that contain at least one (English) *letter*:

```sh
$array = Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\[0-9]*" | 
          ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -notmatch '[a-z]' } |
          Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime | % { $_.Name }
```

Comment: Thank you both again, I can confirm both examples by mklement0 and Ansgar work as expected.